# What is the probability that the expression will have complex solutions

Tags: probability

The coefficients $a$ and $b$ of the squared equation $x ^ 2 + 3a ^ 2x + 3b = 0$ are chosen separately from the interval $[1,3]$. Determine the probability that the equation will have no real solution.

My attemp: the equation will have no real solution
$$9a^4-12b<0\rightarrow b>\frac{3a^4}{4}.$$

$$\Omega={(a,b)|1\leq a,b\leq 3, b>\frac{3a^4}{4}}\rightarrow n(\Omega)=4$$[image]

Are of the set $A$: $$n(A)=\int_1^3\frac{3a^4}{4}da=\frac{726}{20}$$

Finally, $$P(A)=\frac{n(A)}{n(\Omega)}=\frac{363}{40}$$

But I didint know at very well. Please help me. Thanky very much

Answer (score 1):

Definitely your answer cannot be correct, because it is "too" probable :-)
The issue is that you are under three restrictions $1  \leq a \leq 3, 1 \leq b \leq 3$ and $b > \frac{3a^4}{4}$. The total area is indeed $4$ but the so called "favorable" area has to be carefully calculated. You are integrating over $[1,3]$ but if $a$ varies in this interval then it will make $b$ (because of the third restriction) vary beyond the interval $[1,3]$. So what you need to do is the following, consider the curve $b=\frac{3a^4}{4}$:

$$1 \leq b \leq 3 \quad \implies 1 \leq \frac{3a^4}{4} \leq 3 \quad \implies \sqrt[4]{\frac{4}{3}} \leq a \leq \sqrt[4]{4}.$$
You should integrate over this interval.

Comment: where is incorrect

Comment: @betmen12 your probability is coming out of to be $>1$. Note $\frac{363}{40} > 9$.

Comment: yes i know that fact, my mistake is in calculating the integral for sure

Comment: @betmen12 mistake is in the limits for the integral it should be $\int_{4/3^{1/4}}^{4^{1/4}}\frac{3a^4}{4} \, da$.

Comment: ok thanks sir, thanky very much for your help